# MSXML2.XMLHTTP works in a standalone function, access denied when called from a running procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I have a very simple function for returning the HTML code behind a web page from a VBA app:

```
Function GetSource(sURL As String) As Variant
    ' Purpose:   To obtain the HTML text of a web page
    ' Receives:  The URL of the web page
    ' Returns:   The HTML text of the web page in a variant
    Dim oXHTTP As Object, n As Long
    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
    oXHTTP.send
    GetSource = oXHTTP.responsetext
    Set oXHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

It works beautifully when I call it directly -- I get everything there is.  However, whenever I try to call it from a running procedure, I get an "access denied" error (-2147024891).

I've tried playing around with the Internet Explorer object, but it only returns a fraction of what MSXML2.XMLHTTP returns -- and not what I want.  Can anybody tell me how to overcome the error or get the Internet Explorer object to return what MSXML2.XMLHTTP returns?

Comment: @trevbet - It would be better if you included the code that's ***not*** working for you. (ie, how are you calling it, and where are they both located?)

Comment: I'm calling it repeatedly from inside a loop where URL addresses in a table are processed one at a time.  This procedure and the function are in the same access database.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling it?

Comment: I get this frequently if I try and pass HTMLTables outside of the HTML parent document object between function and sub. I would be interested in a decent explanation. I usually go with passing the HTML in a document.

Comment: If I made a working example in Access, could you look at it?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: I guess the web server has some request rate limit, that is why when you call it repeatedly access is denied. How often do you call it? You may add a delay to make the rate lower. Also you may try to simulate several sessions to bypass the limit by cookies processing via `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`. That all depends on the website, so what is the URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal sReq As String) As String
    On Error GoTo onErr
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sReq, False: .Send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, 64)
    End With
  Exit Function
  onErr: MsgBox "Error "&Err &": "&Err.Description,49,"Error opening site"
End Function
```

It's the same idea as you're using with error handling added... I've never had an issue with it.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN: [**`XMLHttpRequest` object** (Methods & Properties)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/ms535874(v=vs.80))
- Wikipedia: [**XMLHttpRequest** (XHR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me with this code.  I tried it out right away.  But it's the same deal as before -- works as a function, generates the same error when you call it from a running procedure.

Comment: How are you calling it? **Please [edit] your question to include the code that's *not working*, as opposed to the code that is working.**

Comment: The code was OK ... the problem is that I was sending the function an HTTP address for an HTTPS page, as you suspected.  (P.S.  I could have been the guy who sold you those TRS-80's!)